# Remove duplicate columns from Spark dataframe without using join

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm processing one DataFrame in PySpark and using `asyncio` to map two different functions over it.

Let's say the DataFrame (`x_df`) looks like this:

| speed | volume |
| --- | --- |
| 26.0 | 234 |
| 32.0 | 123 |

The first function, let's call it `a()`, when applied to this DataFrame, gives me:

| speed | volume | model_version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 26.0 | 234 | v1.0.0 |
| 32.0 | 123 | v1.0.1 |

I'll call this result `a_df`.

The second function, lets call it `b()`, when applied to this DataFrame, gives me:

| speed | volume | model_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 26.0 | 234 | svm |
| 32.0 | 123 | nn |

I'll call this result `b_df`.

I want to combine these 2 DataFrames into one, so that my final result is:

| speed | volume | model_type | model_version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26.0 | 234 | svm | v1.0.0 |
| 32.0 | 123 | nn | v1.0.1 |

I'm doing this using:

```
schema_fields = list(a_df.schema.fields) + list(b_df.schema.fields)
schema = StructType(schema_fields)
merged_df = a_df.rdd.zip(b_df.rdd).map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
```

Now, when I check `merged_df` with `spark.createDataFrame(merged_df, schema).show()`, I see:
these columns:

| speed | volume | model_type | speed | volume | model_version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

How can I de-duplicate the `speed` & `volume` columns? I'm avoiding the `join` because my DataFrames are large and have many common columns (over 10) and also because some of them have complex types instead of just integers or strings.

I'm using asyncio to run the functions `a()` and `b()` concurrently and would prefer to not change that since it's deliberate for getting some performance gains.

Comment: `a()` return dataframe with added column??

Comment: Yes. It does some processing and adds a new column to the original DF.

Comment: when why not call `b()` on `a()`. Do u pass anything in `func a`

Comment: Because I'm using asyncio, both b() and a() run concurrently. The use of asyncio is deliberate to speed up some simple processing.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the core columns seperate and let a and b just return the new columns:

**simple a example:**

```
def a(df): 
    return df.select(
        when(col('speed') % 2 == 0, 'svm').otherwise('nn').alias('model_type')
    )
```

*output of a(df):*

```
+----------+
|model_type|
+----------+
|        nn|
|       svm|
|        nn|
|       svm|
|        nn|
+----------+
```

**simple b example:**

```
def b(df): 
    return df.select(
        when(col('speed') % 2 == 0, 'v1.0.1').otherwise('v1.0.0').alias('model_version')
    )
```

*output of b(df):*

```
+-------------+
|model_version|
+-------------+
|       v1.0.0|
|       v1.0.1|
|       v1.0.0|
|       v1.0.1|
|       v1.0.0|
+-------------+
```

**simple test df:**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"speed": 1, "volume": 1}, 
                            {"speed": 2, "volume": 1}, 
                            {"speed": 3, "volume": 1}, 
                            {"speed": 4, "volume": 1}, 
                            {"speed": 5, "volume": 1}])
```

*output:*

```
+-----+------+
|speed|volume|
+-----+------+
|    1|     1|
|    2|     1|
|    3|     1|
|    4|     1|
|    5|     1|
+-----+------+
```

**zip and map function:**

```
def merge(df1, df2): 
    schema = StructType([*df1.schema, *df2.schema]) 
    return spark.createDataFrame(df1.rdd.zip(df2.rdd).map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1]), schema)
```

**Result**:

```
result_df = merge(
    # Original DF with core columns
    df, 
    merge(
        # df with only model_type
        a(df),
        # df with only model_version
        b(df)
    )
)
```

*output:*

```
+-----+------+----------+-------------+
|speed|volume|model_type|model_version|
+-----+------+----------+-------------+
|    1|     1|        nn|       v1.0.0|
|    2|     1|       svm|       v1.0.1|
|    3|     1|        nn|       v1.0.0|
|    4|     1|       svm|       v1.0.1|
|    5|     1|        nn|       v1.0.0|
+-----+------+----------+-------------+
```